# Java Occurances of Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am in the process of making a game in java.  I was testing out audio playback quickly just to make sure it worked. The below code is is the main method.

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFXPanel();
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //assets grabs a Media object
    new MediaPlayer(Assets.getMedia("aBstracT - Vivacious Vagabonds.mp3")).play();
    //cannot create an anonymous inner class of media player
    new Object() {
        @Override
        public void finalize() {
            System.out.println("Garbage collected");
        }
    };
```

I was confused to find that the music stopped consistently at 40 seconds. My guess was garbage collection (I realized I held no reference to any media object), which I confirmed from the printout.

My questions are as follows:

Why 40 seconds? When does garbage collection occur? I find this odd, and have always assumed that the JVM would attempt to garbage collect only when there are too many unused object (or something, I really have no idea).

Second, is there any way I can mark the JVM to garbage collect an object? It seems inefficient for the JVM to look for references to every object before deciding if it should be removed from memory. I'm also concerned about memory leaks in the event that the garbage collection made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Garbage collection made a mistake"? Don't worry about that, it's written by smarter people than you so you should concentrate on the code *you* write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions: There is no guarantee, that the GC will jump in at any time. If you don't use objects, a GC can be implemented to never happen. It is completely implementation dependent and Sun as well as Oracle have implemented a bunch of different GC implementations. In your case, with your JVM version, it will kick in after 40secs. Adding more memory may change that timer. Running on Android may change it, upgrading to JDK 9 may change it.

Your second question is also the same: You mark an object for GC by removing all references to it. The all so common setting to null of local variables is completely useless. The variable and thus the reference to the object will be removed when you exit the method. 
The GC will not make a mistake. If it does, it is a bug in the JVM and a bigger problem than you could imagine :-)

If you are concerned about GC performance, you are not alone. But to be honest, that is not a big issue any more. You need to be sure about the memory you need to allocate to avoid GC from freezing your app. To get a good overview on the GC mechanisms, have a look here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

To solve your problem, you need to keep a reference on the media player.